# How to use a variable in a sedscript

Tags: sed

I set a variable in a shell script
I then call a sed script and in the sed script I use the variable
That does not seem to work and I needed help on how to achieve that

1. Following works at the command line

> sed -e "s/text/$VAR" testfile

2. Following does not work

**test.sh**

> export VAR=somevar
>   sed -f sedfile testfile

**testfile**

> This is a test file

**sedfile**

> s/text/$VAR/

Also tried

> s/text/${VAR}/

Result

> This is a $VAR file

Expected output

> This is a somevar file

Answer (score 2):

The soft quotes <kbd>"</kbd> on the command line version of your example allow for *shell expansion* of the variable *by your shell*, before sed executes the sed instructions.

The sedfile is not a shell script, it is a sed script interpreted by sed, so no shell expansion of the variable can take place. That is simply not going to work AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

you may wish to generate sedfile using here document syntax

```
cat <<foobar > sedfile
s/text1/${VAR1}/
s/text2/${ANOTHERVAR}/
foobar
```

- `foobar` must be used at the start of the line
- `foobar` can be any string, just use the same string in `<<foobar`

then do the seding

```
sed -f sedfile testfile
```

I expect your sedfile is a bit complex, for one or two substitutions it might not be worth using it.

Comment: This will not be possible in our environment but its a good workaround. Looks like there is no way to perform the task I requested but I will keep checking.